# Error de conversión en C++

Tags: c++

Estaba probando lo de las estructuras en *C++*, tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    
    struct Persona{
        int edad;
        char nombre[20]; 
    }Ivan;
    
    Ivan.edad = 22;
    Ivan.nombre[20] ="david" ;
    cout <<Ivan.edad;
    
    return 0;   
}
```

El problema es que cuando lo compilo me salta el siguiente error:

> error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

El error me lo marca en la línea `Ivan.nombre[6] ="david";`

Answer (score 3):

Ya lo resolví, por si a alguien le sirve, por lo que investigue, las variables tipo char solo pueden ser asignados con = en la declaración de la variable, luego, fuera de la declaración se debe usar strcpy de la librería cstring, asi:

strcpy(Ivan.nombre,"David");

Comment: Eso te pasa por usar `char[]` en vez de `std::string`